# reset GSAP timeline animation & dom changes

Tags: gsap, timeline

Is there a way to completely kill gsap and reset any dom changes that gsap did, e.g any css changes, transforms, pin-spacer. Right now I can use kill, but it won't clear the pin-spacer, and nor it fully clear the css changes that gsap did before its destroyed.

I want to completely wipe/clean gsap animation & revert the dom to same state as it was before initializing gsap.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you've got inline styles besides the ones GSAP sets, clearProps should work for you:

```
gsap.to("*", {clearProps:true})
```